# jQuery Autocomplete Unresponsive

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've used jQuery UI's autocomplete in the past, but for some reason I can't get it to do anything with a TextBox. There are no script errors, and to register it, I'm using:

```
jQuery('#textbox1').autocomplete('/Services/BillService.asmx/GetAllCategories',{
  search: function(event, ui) { alert(0); },
  create: function(event, ui) { alert(2); },
  open: function(event, ui) { alert(1); },
  focus: function(event, ui) { alert(3); }
});
```

Yet nothing happens when I select/type in the textbox. The HTML I have is:

```
<input type="text" class="marg10b" id="textbox1" name="textbox1"/>
```

If I run the script in firebug, one element is matched and i is the correct element, yet something is preventing this from working.

Comment: Are you using [jQueryUI's autocomplete](http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete) or its deprecated predecessor, [jQuery autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)?

Comment: Solved with a tad of massaging to work with ASP.NET and blogged: [jQuery Autocomplete With ASP.NET](http://www.leghumped.com/blog/2012/04/22/jquery-autocomplete-with-asp-net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using jQueryUI's autocomplete. If that's the case, you need to populate the `source` option when you initialize the plugin:

```
jQuery('#textbox1').autocomplete({
    source: '/Services/BillService.asmx/GetAllCategories',
    /* other options */
});
```

Comment: Ah! I was reading it as two parameters for some reason. Thanks.